# How can I implement #include constructs with Flex and YACC?

Tags: parsing, include, yacc, lex

During parsing, if I encounter a include token I want to instruct YACC to open the file specified as input and to begin parsing this. Once this parsing is finished, I want to instruct YACC to return to the file and continue parsing directly after the include  expression. I will restrict the include depth level to one.

Answer (score 9):

The flex manual covers how to do this using yypush_buffer_state() and yypop_buffer_state().

[Here](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html#Multiple-Input-Buffers) is the section of the official manual on using multiple input buffers. There is some sample code.

Comment: DigitilRoss' answer was thorough, and accurate enough.  But best practices win out over cleverness any day.  I saw this 18 minutes ago and now I've got working includes.  Thanks for the link. +1

Answer (score 5):

It's normal to communicate between the lexical and syntactic phases of your processor.

So, recognize the syntax for an include directive in your parser (or, to make things easier, just recognize it in the lexer) and do the switching at the lexical level.

For example, here is a simple language that recognizes standard input lines containing `ab` or `cd` or `.file`. When it sees `.someString` it opens `someString` as an include file and then goes back to reading standard input.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void start_include(char *); int yylex(void); void yyerror(void *);
#define YYSTYPE char *
%}
%%
all:          all others | others;
others:       include_rule | rule_1 | rule_2 | 'Z' { YYACCEPT; };
include_rule: '.' '\n' { start_include($1); };
rule_1:       'a' 'b' '\n' { printf("random rule 1\n"); };
rule_2:       'c' 'd' '\n' { printf("random rule 2\n"); };
%%
FILE * f = NULL;
void start_include(char *s) {
        if ((f = fopen(s, "r")) == NULL)
                abort();
}
int yylex(void) {
        int c;
        static char s[100];
        if (f == NULL)
                f = stdin;
        c = getc(f);
        if (c == EOF) {
                f = stdin;
                c = getc(f);
        }
        if (c == '.') {
                scanf(" %s", s);
                yylval = s;
        } else if (c == EOF)
                return 'Z';
        return c;
}
```

And when we run it...

```
$ cat > toplevel
ab
.myinclude
ab
$ cat > myinclude
cd
cd
$ yacc ip.y && cc -Wall y.tab.c -ly && ./a.out < toplevel
random rule 1
random rule 2
random rule 2
random rule 1
$
```